# Optimum value of minlev in function combine.levels

Tags: r, regression, many-categories

I have a dataset of 306967 rows and 23 columns, and I am building a regression model for predicting a factor based upon 6 other iid variables.
Doing this I encountered an issue of large no of levels present in one of the iid variables, so to sort out it I used `combine.levels` in `Hmisc` package.
The syntax of the general formula is `combine.levels(var,minlev=0.05)`
*Note 0.05 is the default value*.
I used 0.001 as it reduces my levels from 19881 to just 121 and my model ran well.

Is it advisable to use 0.001 as value for it? Is there any technique to judge it and select its value?